# How to turn a set of strings which represent a list into a 2D list

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a set of data read in from a larger CSV file. I want it to match the format I have from another analysis. It is structured as a series of strings with letters and numbers Here it is copy-pasted from Mathematica

```
{"{H, 1}", "{H, 2}", "{H, 3}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}", "{C, \
1}", "{C, 1, H, 1}", "{N, 1}", "{N, 1, H, 1}"}
```

I want to convert it to:

```
{{"H", "1"}, {"H", "2"}, {"H", "3"}, {"Mg", "1"}, {"Mg", "1"}, {"Mg", 
  "1"}, {"N", "1"}, {"N", "1", "H", "1"}}
```

I've tried `Read` and `StringToStream` but I haven't been able to do what I need.

---

I've also solved it. I wasn't on the right track, once I looked at the simple string manipulation tools after posting the question the solution jumped out at me.

```
data = Map[StringTrim[#, ("{" | "}") ...] &, data];
data = Map[StringSplit[#, ","] &, data]
data = StringTrim/@data
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution using `StringSplit`:

```
list = {"{H, 1}", "{H, 2}", "{H, 3}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}",
   "{C, 1}", "{C, 1, H, 1}", "{N, 1}", "{N, 1, H, 1}"};

StringTrim /@ StringSplit[list, {"{", ",", "}"}]
```

> ```
> {{"H", "1"}, {"H", "2"}, {"H", "3"}, {"Mg", "1"}, {"Mg", "1"}, {"Mg", "1"}, 
>  {"C", "1"}, {"C", "1", "H", "1"}, {"N", "1"}, {"N", "1", "H", "1"}}
> ```

Comment: Nice, the two calls in mine were unnecessary. Note, you'll need the second delimiter to be `", "` (note the space) for the elements in the result to not have a leading space.

Comment: @R.M I hadn't noticed the leading spaces. I decided to go for `StringTrim` to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `StringSplit`:

```
strlist = {"{H, 1}", "{H, 2}", "{H, 3}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}", 
  "{Mg, 1}", "{C, 1}", "{C, 1, H, 1}", "{N, 1}", "{N, 1, H, 1}"}   

Flatten[StringSplit[strlist, "{" ~~ x__ ~~ "}" :> StringSplit[x, ", "]], 1]

(* Out[1]= {{"H", "1"}, {"H", "2"}, {"H", "3"}, {"Mg", "1"}, {"Mg", "1"}, 
            {"Mg", "1"}, {"C", "1"}, {"C", "1", "H", "1"}, {"N", "1"}, 
            {"N", "1", "H", "1"}} 
*)
```

---

Per my comment under [Heike's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2258/5), a slight modification of the `StringSplit` solution as:

```
StringSplit[strlist, {"{", ", ", "}"}]
```

would've given the desired result. I'm including it here since she went with `StringTrim` to get rid of the leading space.

Comment: +1. I like this approach more than those based on `ToExpression`, becuase they create new symbols `H`, `Mg`, etc, which is a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more flexible answer is the following:

```
data = {"{H, 1}", "{H, 2}", "{H, 3}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}", "{Mg, 1}",
 "{C, 1}", "{C, 1, H, 1}", "{N, 1}", "{N, 1, H, 1}"}
newData=Map[ToExpression,data]
```

That doesn't assume that  the elements are of string type.

Comment: This converts the whole string into an expression, this can result in some of the letters becoming numbers if they have had a value set. Ex. if Mg=4 somewhere then it would be replaced here.

Comment: Sure. In that case, my suggestion would require you to prepare the input data in a way that is more consistent with Mathematica syntax. I.e., replace "{H, 1}" by "{\"H\", 1}" etc.

Comment: I guess I should have seen that pre-existing symbol definitions would be a problem for you - otherwise you would have just said ToExpression[data]. So I agree you need string manipulation after all...