# Converting a string into a nested list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

The following string can be converted easily into a list with `ToExpression`

```
string = "{{a},{b,c,d},{e,{f,{g}}}}";
ToExpression@string
```

However, if the string contains characters that can be misinterpreted as syntax errors, I run in to problems.

```
string = "{{a},{b,c,d},{e,{[f],{g}}}}"
```

`ToExpression` throws an error since "[f]" isn't valid Wolfram.

<sup>(Side note, is that sentence grammatically correct?  I would write "...isn't valid Java or C".  Is it more appropriate to write "... isn't valid Wolfram Language?")</sup>

I would like to convert a string into a nested list of strings.

For reference [(2242)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2242/7167) starts with data whose `Head` is `List` and doesn't readily appear to work with nested lists, [(43930)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43930/7167) is a similar question focusing on `Graph` and looks promising except that the solution uses *levelspec* in `Cases` which, to my understanding, is not available in `StringCases`.

Comment: What should `[f]` to be turned into? Left untouched?

Comment: @Öskå left untouched. The actual string I am processing has a number of characters that Mathematica would misinterpret, but it looks as if braces {} are treated as they are in M.  Everything other than braces should be left as strings.

Comment: If adding the actual problem is too broad or otherwise inappropriate, I'm happy to roll back.

Comment: For the first case you are expecting `List[List[a],List[b,c,d],List[e,List["[f]",List[g]]]]` as a result?

Comment: Regarding the note I'm afraid "valid Wolfram Language" is the expectation, but I'm going to keep calling it *Mathematica* for the time being.

Comment: @Öskå close, all strings though: `List[List["a"],List["b","c","d"],List["e",List["[f]",List["g"]]]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I just saw your comment that says you want "all strings" so perhaps a different approach:

```
StringReplace["{{a},{b,c,d},{e,{[f],{g}}}}", 
  x : Except["{" | "," | "}"] .. :> "\"" <> x <> "\""] // ToExpression
```

> ```
> {{"a"}, {"b", "c", "d"}, {"e", {"[f]", {"g"}}}}
> ```

---

If that doesn't work consider manipulating the raw box format produced by `parseString`:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]]

fn[string_String] := 
 parseString[string][[1]] /.
  RowBox[x : {"[", __, "]"}] :> "\"" <> x <> "\"" // ToExpression

fn @ "{{a},{b,c,d},{e,{[f],{g}}}}"
```

> ```
> {{a}, {b, c, d}, {e, {"[f]", {g}}}}
> ```

Comment: you may use `SyntaxQ` to check if it's a valid expression

Comment: @hieron What are you proposing?

Comment: If[SyntaxQ@#, ToExpression@#, $Failed] &

Comment: @hieron I'm trying to understand how that is applicable to the problem at hand; are you suggesting using that as part of `StringReplace` or something else?

Comment: as an alternative for the undocumented function.

Comment: @wizard I added an answer below

Answer (score 2):

@Mr.Wizard

```
s = StringReplace["{{a},{b,c,d},{e,{[f],{g}}}}", 
   x : Except["{" | "," | "}"] .. :> "\"" <> x <> "\""] // ToExpression
check = If[SyntaxQ@#, ToExpression@#, #] &;
ReplaceAll[s, x_String :> check@x] // InputForm

(*out*)
{{a}, {b, c, d}, {e, {"[f]", {g}}}}
```

Comment: Finally I see what you were getting at. +1  However this isn't apparently what the OP wants (see comments).

Comment: I know, Pickett found the solution, although your answer was interesting too.